# How to change multiple Urls at once in Postman?

Tags: rest, postman

I have 10+ requests in my Postman collection.

Each time when testing on my `local server` and `testing server` I have to change urls from `'localhost:8000'` to `'test.mysite'` manually.

Is there any solution to change all of them at once ?

Comment: Use variables https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/environments_and_globals/variables

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can do this using the 'manage environments' feature - This can be accessed using the icon under the Send/Save button.

Add a new environment file and set the key to 'url' and the value to 'localhost:8000' - make sure you give the file a name before saving. Go back to your request and select the new file in the drop down menu - This will currently say 'No Environment'. Once you’ve selected your file, replace the url string with `{{url}}/your-route` and hit send. This should now send the local request.

Repeat again but this time add the test server value to the 'url' key. Once that’s in place, all you need to do is switch between the 2 environment files when making requests.

More information about this can be found here https://github.com/DannyDainton/All-Things-Postman/blob/master/Examples/02_createEnvironmentFile.md

Comment: there are 6 Testing servers at my place. had to manually update the host each time. just what i needed. thanks